# How can I implement a FIFO with a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'd like to use a [pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) as [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)). Indices shall be of type [DateTimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex). Values shall be floats.

E.g. when executing the Jupyter cell once

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
time_series = pd.Series(data=[1.0], index=pd.DatetimeIndex([timestamp]))
```

and the following twice

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
time_series = time_series.append(pd.Series(data=[1.0], index=pd.DatetimeIndex([timestamp])))
time_series
```

values with corresponding timestamps are appended as last row (pushed) to the pandas series

```
2020-01-27 12:41:31.341218    1.0
2020-01-27 12:41:33.047248    1.0
2020-01-27 12:48:30.547635    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Removing the first row (pop) can be done with

```
time_series.iloc[1:]
```

which gives

```
2020-01-27 12:41:33.047248    1.0
2020-01-27 12:48:30.547635    1.0
dtype: float64
```

These `push` and `pop` operations function as they should. But probably there is a way to make the execution faster. How can I implement the `push` and `pop` operations more efficiently (performance)?

Comment: Please give an example of input and output.

Comment: @Sid I added exemplary input and output.

Comment: Can you detail what king of functionality you'd like push and pop to perform? You'd like the series to have these methods for instance? So by pushing you'd add a new row at the beginning and by pushing you'd remove the last?

Comment: @yatu Exactly. I thought this is obvious by looking at the Jupyter notebook pseudo code.

Comment: Will give it a go as soon as I have time